# how to get recall and precision from MEKA?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, multilabel-classification, precision-recall

I'm using MEKA for multi-label classification, and it only shows accuracy and F-measure.
Is there any way I can get recall and precision?

Comment: Can you add minimal code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the **Verbosity** in the *Options* dialog (pops up when clicking on the **...** button) to at least **4**.

[image]